# How to suppress net-ssh warnings in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby

I am seeing `ELF` warning with `net-ssh` and I am trying to suppress that warning from printing it on console.

I tried mentioning `$VERBOSE = nil` before I create my `ssh` object but that did not help. I still see the warning messages on the console.

Later I tried to use `Kernel.suppress_warnings` but that seems to be Rails specific.

At last I tried to redirect the warning message to `STDERR` but that did  not work either.

Any help in making this work is really appreciated. Thanks!

Below is the line that is generating warning message.

`$SSH, @ssh = Net::SSH.start(@hostname, @username, :password => @password) if !host.nil?`

Answer (score 0):

From the source code it looks like you might need to set verbose to :silent rather than nil

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that dint work either. In the call to my JRuby jar file, the following workaround did the magic. `java -Djruby.native.verbose=true -Djava.library.path=/lib64 -jar ssh_test.jar `. Problem was that it was not able to load the native C-library for `lib.so`. So passing its path to the command worked.

Answer (score 0):

System is not able to load the native C libraries. This can be fixed by using the following:

```
java -Djruby.native.verbose=true -Djava.library.path=/lib64 -jar ssh_test.jar
```